# SQL combining multiple tables into one issue

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am running the below query in SSMS, which you can see shows the results in multiple tables from the different databases.

How do I combine the tables into one?

I have tried adding a UNION and UNION ALL into `SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) +` but I get a `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.` error

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
DECLARE @table table(dbname sysname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)

INSERT INTO @table(dbname)
SELECT NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM sys.databases where name like '%AccountsLive'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) +
'SELECT c_broker, det_costheader, cuname, ch_name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ch_date_req,103) AS ''Flight_Date'', IIF(OUT.outstanding>0, ''Yes'', ''No'') AS ''Anything_Outstanding?'', sum(c_grossmargin)/2 AS ''Gross_Margin'' FROM ' 
+ QUOTENAME(dbname) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS + '.dbo.AT_ACS_COMMISSIONS AS COM
LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(dbname) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS + '.dbo.AT_ACS_PROJECTOUTSTANDING AS OUT
ON COM.det_costheader = OUT.project
WHERE c_broker = ''HKGCGOJT''
GROUP BY det_costheader, c_broker, cuname, ch_name, ch_date_req, outstanding'
FROM    @table

exec( @Sql );
```

Comment: copy your sql into text to your question and format it nicely before someone can help you

Comment: sorry - i thought the picture would be better...i've edited it show the code in text now

Comment: Please add second query also which you want to union.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur - there is no second query, just this one. when i run this query it produces results into individual tables depending on the databse. i just want one table to be produced for this query....is this possible?

Comment: insert the result into temp table

Comment: is inserting a temp table the only possible way? i'm trying to avoid that as once i have managed to solve just having one table, i am putting the code into a VBA script......thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the columns have different collations in different databases then you need to add a `COLLATE` to them. I've added a couple to show you how it's done.

Notes:

- The table variable is not necessary here
- Use `STRING_AGG` (or `FOR XML`) to aggregate, [do not use variable coalescing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260573/sql-server-string-concat-with-order-by-and-subquery), [it is unsafe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697).
- If you intend to add parameters, then use `sp_executesql` and pass through parameters to the dynamic part. **Do not** concatenate parameters into the query.

```sql
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql =
(SELECT
    STRING_AGG(

N'SELECT
    c_broker COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    det_costheader,
    cuname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    ch_name,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ch_date_req, 103) AS [Flight_Date],
    IIF(OUT.outstanding > 0, ''Yes'', ''No'') AS [Anything_Outstanding?],
    sum(c_grossmargin) / 2 AS [Gross_Margin]
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_COMMISSIONS AS COM
LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_PROJECTOUTSTANDING AS OUT
ON COM.det_costheader = OUT.project
WHERE c_broker = ''HKGCGOJT''
GROUP BY det_costheader, c_broker, cuname, ch_name, ch_date_req, outstanding
',
    CAST (N'
UNION ALL
' AS nvarchar(max)) )

FROM sys.databases d
where name like '%AccountsLive'
);

exec( @Sql );
```

---

If you are on old version of SQL Server that does not have `STRING_AGG`, then you need to use `FOR XML` to aggregate:

```sql
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql =
STUFF(
(SELECT
    NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +
N'SELECT
    c_broker COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    det_costheader,
    cuname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    ch_name,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ch_date_req, 103) AS [Flight_Date],
    IIF(OUT.outstanding > 0, ''Yes'', ''No'') AS [Anything_Outstanding?],
    sum(c_grossmargin) / 2 AS [Gross_Margin]
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_COMMISSIONS AS COM
LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_PROJECTOUTSTANDING AS OUT
ON COM.det_costheader = OUT.project
WHERE c_broker = ''HKGCGOJT''
GROUP BY det_costheader, c_broker, cuname, ch_name, ch_date_req, outstanding
'
FROM sys.databases d
where name like '%AccountsLive'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)

.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');

exec( @Sql );
```

**I would advise to use `PRINT @Sql` for testing purposes, to ensure the generated SQL is actually valid.**

Comment: Thanks for the help @Charlieface - however, I am getting `STRING_AGG is not a recognised built-in function name` in SSMS? Also, a `must declare the scaler variable "@SQL"`...?

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for all your help with this, greatly appreciated.....just one last issue (hopefully) is an incorrect syntax near UNION?

Comment: Whoops extraneous `;` from when I copied yours. Check it over with `print @Sql`

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you for the help!